# `smbstatus` not showing NetBIOS name

Tags: samba, samba4

I'm upgrading a Samba server from 3.0.37 to 4.4.3, and it seems that on 4.4.3, the `smbstatus` utility no longer displays the NetBIOS name of connected clients.

On 3.0.37, `smbstatus -p` looks like this:

```
PID     Username      Group         Machine
-------------------------------------------------------------------
30042   user          grp           client-name   (10.0.0.1)
```

On 4.4.3, `smbstatus -p` looks like this:

```
PID     Username     Group     Machine                          Protocol Version  Encryption           Signing
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
25540   user         grp       10.0.0.1 (ipv4:10.0.0.1:52269)   NT1               -                    -
```

The above output is from the two versions of Samba running on the same server (not simultaneously) with the same `smb.conf` (which is pretty basic). The client is the same in both outputs, and is a Windows 7 Pro machine.

I tried setting `hostname lookups = yes` in `smb.conf`, but this results in displaying the DNS name of the client rather than its NetBIOS name.

Is there a way to get `smbstatus` in 4.4.3 to display the NetBIOS name like before, or is this output format just the new normal? Or maybe this behavior is somehow specific to my environment?